# C#, Craft.Net throwing JSON.Net Exception. Fails to launch

Tags: c#, json.net, minecraft

I began working on a modded Minecraft launcher. I keep getting this error when I pass the user name and password to Craft.Nets Session.DoLogin()

```
private void bLaunch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sessionID = Session.DoLogin(lblUser.Text, lblPass.Text).SessionId;
}
```

An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Additional information: ISerializable type 'Craft.Net.Client.Session+MinecraftAuthenticationException' does not have a valid constructor. To correctly implement ISerializable a constructor that takes SerializationInfo and StreamingContext parameters should be present. Path '', line 1, position 107.

What exactly is happening? Is it something to do with JSON? Or is it a problem with Craft.Net?

DotMinecraft.cs, PKCSKeyGenerator.cs, RuntimeInfo.cs and Session.cs from the Craft.Net 1.7.x branch are included in the project. Json.Net from the NuGet is also included

Session Code that is throwing error:

```
var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            try
            {
                var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://authserver.mojang.com/authenticate");
                request.ContentType = "application/json";
                request.Method = "POST";
                var token = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                var blob = new AuthenticationBlob(username, password, token);
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(blob);
                var stream = request.GetRequestStream();
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
                    writer.Write(json);
                var response = request.GetResponse();
                stream = response.GetResponseStream();
                var session = serializer.Deserialize<Session>(new JsonTextReader(new StreamReader(stream)));
                session.UserName = username;
                return session;
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                var stream = e.Response.GetResponseStream();
                var json = new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd();
                stream.Close();
                throw JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MinecraftAuthenticationException>(json);
            }
```

Comment: I'm wondering if the exception you're getting is masking the real exception. It looks like an `MinecraftAuthenticationException` was throw, but couldn't be serialized... is the `DoLogin()` happening on a server somewhere and you're serializing results back to the client? You might wrap that line in a `try/catch` and log the `.ToString()` of the exception to see if that'll help you find the root issue.

Comment: The session.cs has a try/catch (view edit). How do I log the .ToString() exactly?

Comment: I don't have any prior experience with Json, or serialising things. So a lot of this is new to me.

Comment: When you debug the code, does it end up in the catch? If so, can inspect the contents of json variable to see what's in there?

Comment: json "{\"error\":\"ForbiddenOperationException\",\"errorMessage\":\"Invalid credentials. Invalid username or password.\"}" string.     Ok this is what I was looking for. Invalid user and password, Thankyou!

Comment: It's possible this question may be too specific in scope to be helpful to others (since it was about unmasking a hidden error). I'll leave it up to you on whether to delete it or not. If you chose to keep it open, either you or I should write up an answer and accept it. Let me know what you'd like :)

Comment: Ill write up an answer soon, I just want to get this launcher to finally launch :D

Comment: Hey, I made Craft.Net and I was browsing [minecraft] questions when I saw this. I've since fixed that bug, update your copy of Session.cs and it should work fine.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what the problem was that I was having at the time, but it would seem that every thing works now with the update.